# WordPress website is not accessible on Safari

Tags: wordpress, windows, macos, safari, cross-browser

I have a WordPress site and it's not accessible when using Safari on Windows, Mac, as well as an online tool - Browserling. The URL of the site is https://www.ihc.ae/

The error is:
Safari cannot open the page because Safari cannot establish a secure connection to the server "www.ihc.ae".

I've tried using browserling to access the website: https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/safari/5.1/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ihc.ae%2F

But the error is the same.

Please advise a fix for this.

Comment: I tested using Mac OSX and Safari. Works just fine. I can confirm that SSL cert. is successfully loaded.

Comment: @OzgurSar could you confirm why the site is not accessible on https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/safari/5.1/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ihc.ae%2F

Comment: I don't know why browserling can not access (maybe a firewall issue between your hosting company and browserling) but you can also access using any web proxy or VPN such as https://www.proxysite.com/

Comment: @OzgurSar Thanks. Do you know of any online tool where I can access a Safari browser without a similar issue?
I need to fix some parts of the site that aren't looking fine on Safari.